# Firefox freezing on youtube

Tags: 14.04, firefox

The title says it all. Once I try accessing youtube, firefox freezes and I have to force kill it with `killall firefox` or `xkill firefox` . The issue is youtube specific; other video websites , such as vimeo or dailymotion work. 
The following didn't help:

- `sudo apt-get purge firefox` and reinstall
- `-safe-mode`
- Disabling HTML5 or flash

Ubuntu 14.04, Firefox 40.0.3

**Update 1**

In private mode, with renamed profile, or with `.mozilla` directory removed, firefox loads youtube alright. But as soon as I sign in to my account, it lags, which makes me resort to `killall` .

Comment: What kind of flash plug-in you use?

Comment: Well, then the problem is in your user profile folder. There's a good chance it's an extension. Try to disable all extensions. If the problem goes away, it's an extension problem. Try re-enabling them one by one until the problem occurs again. But to be honest, I'd deal with a problematic profile folder by copying the important stuff (e.g. places.sqlite), deleting the folder and starting anew. I find it easier to re-install all extensions and make a few configurations than to spend twice the amount of time debugging, not to mention Firefox tends to get faster with a fresh profile folder. YMMV.

Comment: @Yamaho I've done all that stuff over and over and over.  Deleted `.mozilla` folder ? Check. Deleted `.macromedia` folder ? check. Even tried older versions of firefox.  *with* `.mozilla` folder removed, as if it was all a new install. Nothing. Nill. Zip. Nada

Comment: What does your latest Firefox health report say?

Comment: After upgrade for Firefox came out, problem disappeared. Definitely was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This might work: [Reset Firefox Profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settingsre)

Press the Refresh Firefox blue button.

Comment: Link says page not found. In any case i upgraded firefox and it's working fine now. Definitely was some bug

Comment: the link, I had a typo.  This is the correct link:  [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is adding [www.youtube.com###guide-container](http://www.youtube.com###guide-container) 
to any adblocker (uBlock in my case) solved the freezing Problem and disabled the left side Menu.